# How to loop through jason data and display it in data list tag (dl)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json

I'm trying to loop through some JSON data (var mydata) and mydata is an array of two elements, the second element  in the array

`mydata[1]` is a multidimensional array, I need to display the first element i.e `mydata[0]` in a dt and display elements from mydata[1] in a dd within that.

I tried every option but I'm really stuck and I need any help on this. Below is my code:

```
var mydata = [
  [{
      "id": "67",
      "name": "Baby & Toddler Clothing "
  }, {
      "id": "68",
      "name": "Kids' Clothing, Shoes & Accessories"
  }, {
      "id": "69",
      "name": "Costumes, Reenactment Theater"
  }],
  [
    [{
        "id": "572",
        "name": "Baby Clothing Accessories "
    }, {
        "id": "573",
        "name": "Baby Shoes"
    }],
    [{
        "id": "579",
        "name": "Boys Clothing [Sizes 4 & Up] "
    }, {
        "id": "580",
        "name": "Boys Shoes"
    }],
    [{
        "id": "588",
        "name": "Costumes"
    }, {
        "id": "589",
        "name": "Reenactment & Theater "
    }]
  ]


 ]


function getCategories(id){
       $.ajax({
        url: '{$getcatUrl}',
        type: 'POST',
        data: {category_id: id},
        success: function (data) { 
                    data = jQuery.parseJSON(data);
                     //console.log(data); return;
                    if(data.length > 0){ 
                         firstdata = data[0];
                         secdata = data[1];                        
                         for(var i = 0; i < firstdata.length; i++) {
                             level_1 = firstdata[i].name;
                             level_1_id = firstdata[i].id;
                         for(var j = 0; j< secdata.length; j++){
                           if(secdata[i][j] !== undefined){
                             level_2='';
                             level_2 = secdata[i][j].name;
                             level_2_id = secdata[i][j].d;
                          }

                                console.log(level_2);

                        }

                        var dldata = $(
                             '<dl>'+
                                   "<dt href='" + level_1_id + "'>" + level_1 + "</dt>"+
                                   "<dd href='" + level_2_id + "'>" + level_2 + "</dd>"+

                             '</dl>'
                       );   
                    }

                  }else{
                      console.log('no item for this categories');
                 }
               },
            error: function(jqXHR, errMsg) {
             // handle error
                console.log(errMsg);
            }
        });
   }
```

The var level_1 and level_1_id works fine, but i keep getting error for variable level_2, the error says can't read property 'name' of undefined, any solution to this problem will be appreciated and am also open to new ideas about doing it better,

Comment: Invalid json string, miswriting json, code formatting and question punctuation is very annoying. Please fix. Also read [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) please. Verify correct json string using [jsonlint.com](https://jsonlint.com).

Comment: please check and clean up your question, at least spell JSON correctly to start with! And it's tagged wrong, there is no PHP here, only Javascript!

Comment: @ADyson, Thanks for the correction, but actually it was typo error, and the tag, initially there was a php code in the question but i remove it to make it simple so i never changed the tag when i edited the question, but i would be happy if in anyway you can still help with the question.

Comment: Well you can edit the tags now, you know, then more people with JS expertise will see it. I made those comments so you could correct the mistakes and improve the question, make it easier to answer.

Comment: The reason for your error will be because the code is making incorrect assumptions about the data structure. Have you used the Javascript debugger built into your browser to step through the code and check the values of your variables at each line? It should make it much easier to see where the logical error is.

Comment: Although...I just ran your code (simplified, without the ajax), and it works without error using the sample data supplied as the input. See https://jsfiddle.net/buo28k1L/ . I don't know if the final output is actually what you expect, you didn't make that very clear, but certainly there's no console error.

Comment: @ADyson a lot thanks to you, i will remove the php tags now,  i checked you jsfiddle and that's exactly what i wanted and what i was getting, but the problem is only the last element in the json array was printed, thanks alot anyway

Comment: So...it works as you want, or not? I'm not quite sure from your comment. If it's not what you wanted, you'll have to give me an exact example of what the expected output is from that sample data. Anyway I don't get where your stated error was coming from, because it's not coming from that code & data combination.

Comment: @ADyson let me put self clear a bit,  the json array has two element, the first element which is data[0] has 3 element, but from this element only the last one which is  (Costumes, Reenactment Theater) was printed, also from the second element which is data[1] which also itself is an array of 3 element only last element was printed , data[1][2] (Reenactment & Theater). so how do i make all other element also be printed

Comment: So basically you want to print out all the data from the JSON, yes? Or maybe just the names, not the IDs? In that case loop through each (name) element and output some HTML for it directly. Right now, you overwrite the `level_1` and `level_2` variables each time your `for` loops run. So by the time you get to the code which makes the HTML, they have been overwritten multiple times and only the last version remains, and you only print that once in any case. It's a basic - but surprisingly common, I see it on SO a lot - logical error.

Comment: @ADyson yes i want to print all the data from json, and what you said exactly is where my problem is i think each time i loop through the json array it's been overwritten, i have created another question here to show the exact output i expect, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49922584/how-to-print-json-data-in-data-list-dl thanks once again you've help a lot and i think am getting closer with your help and guide

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/buo28k1L/16/ this is what you want, I think. If you can confirm, I will write this as the answer

Comment: @ADyson, i big thanks to you, this is what i want exactly what i want, please write this as the answer and i will accept it

Comment: Or https://jsfiddle.net/buo28k1L/24/ where it generates a separate dl for each item in data[0] - is that a better style of presentation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Essentially the problem is that you overwrite the `level_1` and `level_2` variables each time your `for` loops run. So by the time you get to the code which makes the HTML, they have been overwritten multiple times and only the last version remains, and you only print that once in any case.

This will resolve it - in this case by generating the HTML elements directly within each loop, although you could of course do it by appending to a variable and then outputting everything at the end, if that's your preference.

```js
var data = [
  [{
    "id": "67",
    "name": "Baby & Toddler Clothing "
  }, {
    "id": "68",
    "name": "Kids' Clothing, Shoes & Accessories"
  }, {
    "id": "69",
    "name": "Costumes, Reenactment Theater"
  }],
  [
    [{
      "id": "572",
      "name": "Baby Clothing Accessories "
    }, {
      "id": "573",
      "name": "Baby Shoes"
    }],
    [{
      "id": "579",
      "name": "Boys Clothing [Sizes 4 & Up] "
    }, {
      "id": "580",
      "name": "Boys Shoes"
    }],
    [{
      "id": "588",
      "name": "Costumes"
    }, {
      "id": "589",
      "name": "Reenactment & Theater "
    }]
  ]
]

if (data.length > 0) {
  var content = $("#content");
  firstdata = data[0];
  secdata = data[1];

  for (var i = 0; i < firstdata.length; i++) {
    var dl = $("#content").append("<dl/>");
    dl.append("<dt href='" + firstdata[i].id + "'>" + firstdata[i].name + "</dd>");

    for (var j = 0; j < secdata.length; j++) {
      if (secdata[i][j] !== undefined) {
        dl.append("<dd href='" + secdata[i][j].id + "'>" + secdata[i][j].name + "</dd>");
      }
    }
  }
  content.append(dl);
} else {
  console.log('no item for this categories');
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="content"></div>
```