# How to print json data in data list (dl)

Tags: javascript, json

I'm trying to loop through a json data which is a multidimensional array, but each time I loop through this array I only get the last element of the array printed.

```js
var data = [


[{
      "id": "67",
      "name": "Baby & Toddler Clothing "
  }, {
      "id": "68",
      "name": "Kids' Clothing, Shoes & Accessories"
  }, {
      "id": "69",
      "name": "Costumes, Reenactment Theater"
  }],
  [
    [{
        "id": "572",
        "name": "Baby Clothing Accessories "
    }, {
        "id": "573",
        "name": "Baby Shoes"
    }],
    [{
        "id": "579",
        "name": "Boys Clothing [Sizes 4 & Up] "
    }, {
        "id": "580",
        "name": "Boys Shoes"
    }],
    [{
        "id": "588",
        "name": "Costumes"
    }, {
        "id": "589",
        "name": "Reenactment & Theater "
    }]
  ]


 ]





  if (data.length > 0) {
  firstdata = data[0];
  secdata = data[1];
  for (var i = 0; i < firstdata.length; i++) {
    level_1 = firstdata[i].name;
    level_1_id = firstdata[i].id;
    for (var j = 0; j < secdata.length; j++) {
      if (secdata[i][j] !== undefined) {
        level_2 = '';
        level_2 = secdata[i][j].name;
        level_2_id = secdata[i][j].d;
      }

      console.log(level_2);

    }

    var dldata = $(
      '<dl>' +
      "<dt href='" + level_1_id + "'>" + level_1 + "</dt>" +
      "<dd href='" + level_2_id + "'>" + level_2 + "</dd>" +

      '</dl>'
    );

    $("#content").html(dldata);
  }

} else {
  console.log('no item for this categories');
}
```

My problem as I stated above is, after running the code only the last element in the array is printed as [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/buo28k1L/) shows.

In the fiddle *Costumes*, *Reenactment Theater*, and *Reenactment & Theater* were printed which is the last element of each json array above.

My expected output is as below:

```
Baby & Toddler Clothing
   Baby Clothing Accessories
   Baby Shoes`


Kids' Clothing, Shoes & Accessories
   Boys Clothing [Sizes 4 & Up]
   Boys Shoes


Costumes, Reenactment Theater
   Costumes
   Reenactment & Theater
```

I expected the above output however what I actually got was just:

```
Costumes, Reenactment Theater
   Costumes
```

I hope readers understand my question and I thank you in advance for any help.

Comment: what is your expected output?

Comment: @kalai thanks a lot i will edit my question to show my expected output

Comment: I think it's becuase the last part (defining dldata) is not concatinating the three runs of the loop. It's just showing the last one that ran through the loop. Try changing $("#content").html(dldata) to $("#content").append(dldata)

Comment: This is a duplicate of what you made earlier, don't ask the same question twice.

Answer (score 0):

It's because each time the first loop runs it clears the contents of your content div. Try using:

`$("content").append(dldata);`

instead and you should see all three outputs as expected.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this (I did it quickly and it need to be refactored):

```js
var data = [


[{
      "id": "67",
      "name": "Baby & Toddler Clothing "
  }, {
      "id": "68",
      "name": "Kids' Clothing, Shoes & Accessories"
  }, {
      "id": "69",
      "name": "Costumes, Reenactment Theater"
  }],
  [
    [{
        "id": "572",
        "name": "Baby Clothing Accessories "
    }, {
        "id": "573",
        "name": "Baby Shoes"
    }],
    [{
        "id": "579",
        "name": "Boys Clothing [Sizes 4 & Up] "
    }, {
        "id": "580",
        "name": "Boys Shoes"
    }],
    [{
        "id": "588",
        "name": "Costumes"
    }, {
        "id": "589",
        "name": "Reenactment & Theater "
    }]
  ]


 ]





  if (data.length > 0) {
  firstdata = data[0];
  secdata = data[1];
  result = '<dl>';
  firstdata.map((firstD, i) => {
    result += "<dt href='" + firstD.id + "'>" + firstD.name + "</dt>";
    secdata[i].map(secD => result += "<dd href='" + secD.id + "'>" + secD.name + "</dd>");
    
    });
result += '</dl>';


    console.log(result);


} else {
  console.log('no item for this categories');
}
```